# Having 2 Nextjs applications on the same domain

Tags: nginx, next.js

I have two NextJS applications. There are two ports on my server.
I am trying to serve them using nginx.
I currently have them on example.com and test.example.com, and they work as intended with the following configuration for nginx:

```
# upstream for the next JS example.
upstream nextjsExample {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

# upstream for the next JS text.
upstream nextjsTest {
    server 127.0.0.1:6000;
}

# server pointing to the next JS example
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextjsExample;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# server pointing to the next JS test
server {
    server_name test.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextjsTest;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

I want to have the second application on example.com/test. I tried to achieve this with the following nginx configuration:

```
# upstream for the next JS example.
upstream nextjsExample {
    server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

# upstream for the next JS text.
upstream nextjsTest {
    server 127.0.0.1:6000;
}

# server pointing to the next JS example
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextjsExample;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location /test {
        proxy_pass http://nextjsTest;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}

# server pointing to the next JS test
server {
    server_name test.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextjsTest;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Nextjs test application on the /test address still tries to load some data from example.com/_next/static and example.com/_next/img=..., so the Nextjs example application is called, so those files are not found, so the page is not shown properly.

I know I can merge my two Nextjs applications into one big application, but I prefer to keep them separate since different people are responsible for developing and maintaining them.

Is there a way to do this? Either by nginx configurations or by NextJs configurations? Any help would be appreciated.